# issue to download Hyperledger Fabric binaries and mirrors in Windows 7 Git CMD

Tags: git, docker, curl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to install Hyperledger Fabric version 2.2.0 according to [the official Hyperledger Fabric Docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/release-2.2/install.html). My computer is Windows 7, 64 bit.

I have installed Git, curl and docker strictly according to the instructions in it,and I have confirmed many times that their versions meet the requirements.All the prerequisites are ready.

But when I execute

> curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s - 2.2.0 1.4.7

(Here，I have to replace shortened links with full URLs.So the CURL command I executed contains a shortened url, as shown in the  [figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koIT6.png))
or

> curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.shE | bash -s

(Here，I have to replace shortened links with full URLs.So the CURL command I executed contains a shortened url, as shown in the  [figure2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Dew.png))

there are always problems :

> Curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed

How should I do? Could anyone help? I really appreciate it.

[the issue figure when executing the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zdkf.png)

Answer (score 0):

As docker doesn't work well in Windows 7, my suggestion would be to use Virtualbox and install Linux ubuntu to start your Hyperledger Fabric learning.